# ggplo2 in R: geom_segment displays different line than geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, shapes, segment

Say I have this data frame:

```
treatment <- c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6),rep("C",6),rep("D",6),rep("E",6),rep("F",6))
year <- as.numeric(c(1999:2004,1999:2004,2005:2010,2005:2010,2005:2010,2005:2010))
variable <- c(runif(6,4,5),runif(6,5,6),runif(6,3,4),runif(6,4,5),runif(6,5,6),runif(6,6,7))
se <- c(runif(6,0.2,0.5),runif(6,0.2,0.5),runif(6,0.2,0.5),runif(6,0.2,0.5),runif(6,0.2,0.5),runif(6,0.2,0.5))
id <- 1:36
df1 <- as.data.table(cbind(id,treatment,year,variable,se))

df1$year <- as.numeric(df1$year)
df1$variable <- as.numeric(df1$variable)
df1$se <- as.numeric(df1$se)
```

As I mentioned in a previous question ([draw two lines with the same origin using ggplot2 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511091/draw-two-lines-with-the-same-origin-using-ggplot2-in-r)), I wanted to use ggplot2 to display my data in a specific way.

I managed to do so using the following script:

```
y1 <- df1[df1$treatment=='A'&df1$year==2004,]$variable
y2 <- df1[df1$treatment=='B'&df1$year==2004,]$variable
y3 <- df1[df1$treatment=='C'&df1$year==2005,]$variable
y4 <- df1[df1$treatment=='D'&df1$year==2005,]$variable
y5 <- df1[df1$treatment=='E'&df1$year==2005,]$variable
y5 <- df1[df1$treatment=='E'&df1$year==2005,]$variable
y6 <- df1[df1$treatment=='F'&df1$year==2005,]$variable

p <- ggplot(df1,aes(x=year,y=variable,group=treatment,color=treatment))+
geom_line(aes(y = variable, group = treatment, linetype = treatment, color = treatment),size=1.5,lineend = "round") +
scale_linetype_manual(values=c('solid','solid','solid','dashed','solid','dashed')) +
geom_point(aes(colour=factor(treatment)),size=4)+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=variable-se,ymax=variable+se),width=0.2,size=1.5)+
guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape=NA,linetype = c("solid", "solid",'solid','dashed','solid','dashed'))))

p+labs(title="Title", x="years", y = "Variable 1")+
  theme_classic() +
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1998:2010), labels=c(1998:2010),limits=c(1998.5,2010.5))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=2004, y=y1, xend=2005, yend=y3),colour='blue1',size=1.5,linetype='solid')+
  geom_segment(aes(x=2004, y=y1, xend=2005, yend=y4),colour='blue1',size=1.5,linetype='dashed')+
  geom_segment(aes(x=2004, y=y2, xend=2005, yend=y5),colour='red3',size=1.5,linetype='solid')+
  geom_segment(aes(x=2004, y=y2, xend=2005, yend=y6),colour='red3',size=1.5,linetype='dashed')+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue1','red3','blue1','blue1','red3','red3'))+
  theme(text = element_text(size=12))
```

As you can see I used both geom_line and geom_segment to display the lines for my graph.

[image: figure]

It's almost perfect but if you look closely, the segments that are drawn (between 2004 and 2005) do not display the same line size, even though I used the same arguments values in the script (i.e. `size=1.5` and `linetype='solid'` or `dashed`).

Of course I could change manually the size of the segments to get similar lines, but when I do that, segments are not as smooth as the lines using `geom_line`.
Also, I get the same problem (different line shapes) by including the `size` or `linetype` arguments within the `aes()` argument.

Do you have any idea what causes this difference and how I can get the exact same shapes for both my segments and lines ?

Comment: I think the lines have the same size. It seems to be a problem with the rasterization algorithm. Since I got different numbers due to randomization, the issue seems to happens on year 2006 to 2007 where only `geom_line` is used.

Comment: indeed when I delete the 'colour' arguments in the 'geom_segment' sections, colors are changed... 
But I don't understand what you are saying for 2006 to 2007. The way the dataframe is built, geom_line should be applied for ranges from 1999 to 2004 and/or from 2005 to 2010, right ?

Comment: maybe a solution would be adding a line with an 'override.aes'-like argument for those segments, like for the legend ? If that even makes sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an anti-aliasing issue with geom_segment, but that seems like a somewhat cumbersome approach to begin with.  I think I have resolved your issue by duplicating the `A` and `B` treatments in the original data frame.

```
# First we are going to duplicate and rename the 'shared' treatments
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 %>% 
  filter(treatment %in% c("A", "B")) %>% 
  mutate(treatment = ifelse(treatment == "A",
                            "AA", "BB")) %>% 
  bind_rows(df1) %>% # This rejoins with the original data
  # Now we create `treatment_group` and `line_type` variables
  mutate(treatment_group = ifelse(treatment %in% c("A", "C", "D", "AA"),
                                  "treatment1",
                                  "treatment2"), # This variable will denote color
         line_type = ifelse(treatment %in% c("AA", "BB", "D", "F"),
                            "type1",
                            "type2")) %>% # And this variable denotes the line type

# Now pipe into ggplot
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = variable,
             group = interaction(treatment_group, line_type), # grouping by both linetype and color
             color = treatment_group)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = variable, linetype = line_type), 
            size = 1.5, lineend = "round") +
  geom_point(size=4) +
  # The rest here is more or less the same as what you had
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = variable-se, ymax = variable+se), 
                width = 0.2, size = 1.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue1','red3')) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('dashed', 'solid')) +
  labs(title = "Title", x = "Years", y = "Variable 1") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1998:2010), 
                     limits = c(1998.5, 2010.5))+
  theme_classic() +
  theme(text = element_text(size=12))
```

Which will give you the following[image]

My numbers are different since they were randomly generated.

You can then modify the legend to your liking, but my recommendation is using something like `geom_label` and then be sure to set `check_overlap = TRUE`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The output is exactly what I was looking for, so thank you very much ! Plus I learned a few things here: 
I didn't know you could use `df1 %>%` and then write down the script of ggplot to run it directly. 
And this is also very helpful to change parts of my dataframe only for this purpose (or any other purpose), as when I use `View(df1)` thereafter, the treatments are still `A` and `B`, not `AA` and `BB`. Thanks again.

Comment: quick qestion though, I don't understand why you replaced `A` with `AA` and `B` with `BB`. The way I understand the script, `treatment1` equals `A` + `C` + `D` + `AA`, but why this is more convenient than just `A` + `C` + `D` ?

Comment: Sure thing.  Ultimately I didn't replace `A` and `B` with `AA` and `BB`, but rather duplicated them and then combined them with the unaltered, original data (that's what the `bind_rows` argument does).  I used `AA` and `BB` arbitrarily, so that I could easily name the linetype grouping and the color groupings.  Currently what my `ggplot` does, is that it plots a full solid line from 1999 to 2010, and then a full dotted line from 1999 to 2010.

Comment: If you wanted, in the above code you could rename the `AA` and `BB` as just `A` and `B` AFTER you have successfully created the two grouping variables (between `mutate` and `ggplot`)

Comment: No problem!  If you think this satisfactorily answers your question, feel free to accept it as an answer, although there is no obligation to do so.  Thanks!